# Load multiple images one after another in a canvas with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to load multiple images from a folder and do something(crop) with each image and after closing  i want the next image to be loaded for cropping and so on......but at present my code only loads one image and after working on it closes as it supposed to but the next image doesn't load onto the canvas.
I think the problem is in 'load_image' function or the calling to that function.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

array = []
tuplee = ()
count = 0
d = 0
f = 1
FileDir = ""

#Load all files from directory
File = os.listdir('frames/')
#print(File)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

#setting up a tkinter frame and canvas
frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief = SUNKEN)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=1, width=950, height=600)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

FileDir = 'C:/Users/cvcrb/Desktop/NumberPlate/frames/' + File[0]
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(FileDir))
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

def load_image():
    FileDir = 'C:/Users/cvcrb/Desktop/NumberPlate/frames/' + File[f]
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(FileDir))
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

    #root.update_idletasks()
    #root.after(100,load_image)

#function to be called when mouse is clicked
def printcoords(event):
    global count
    global d
    global FileDir
    global f
    for i in range(1):
        array.append(event.x)
        array.append(event.y)
        tuplee = tuple(array)
        print (tuplee)
        count += 1
        if count == 2:                  
            print ("Cropping...")
            crop(FileDir, tuplee, 'cropped%d.jpg' % d)
            d += 1
            print ("Cropped")
            count = 0
            canvas.destroy()            #canvas closes after 2 clicks
        load_image()                    #should load the next image 

#mouseclick event
canvas.bind("<Button 1>",printcoords)



#function to crop a certain area using coordinates
def crop(image_path, coords, saved_location):
    image_obj = Image.open(image_path)
    cropped_image = image_obj.crop(coords)
    cropped_image.save(saved_location)
    image_obj.close()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake in your code is that you don't change your variable `f`, therefore your `load_image()` just loads the same image over and over again.

Second major issue was that you don't need to do `canvas.destroy()`. It's enough to do `canvas.delete("all")` before creating a new image.

Here is your modified code that works well for me:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

array = []
tuplee = ()
f = 1
FileDir = ""

#Load all files from directory
File = os.listdir('frames/')
#print(File)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

#setting up a tkinter frame and canvas
frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief = SUNKEN)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=1, width=950, height=600)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

FileDir = 'frames/' + File[0]
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(FileDir))
cimg = canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

def load_image():
    global canvas, img, FileDir
    FileDir = 'frames/' + File[f]
    canvas.delete("all")
    #del img
    #del canvas
    #canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=1, width=950, height=600)
    #canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(FileDir))
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

    #root.update_idletasks()
    #root.after(100,load_image)

#function to be called when mouse is clicked
def printcoords(event):
    global FileDir
    global f
    global array
    array.append(event.x)
    array.append(event.y)
    tuplee = tuple(array)
    print (tuplee)
    if len(tuplee)==4:
        print ("Cropping...")
        crop(FileDir, tuplee, 'cropped%d.jpg' % f)
        print ("Cropped")
        array = []
        f += 1
        load_image()                    #should load the next image

#mouseclick event
canvas.bind("<Button 1>",printcoords)



#function to crop a certain area using coordinates
def crop(image_path, coords, saved_location):
    image_obj = Image.open(image_path)
    cropped_image = image_obj.crop(coords)
    cropped_image.save(saved_location)
    image_obj.close()


root.mainloop()
```

NOTE: I deleted `C:/Users/cvcrb/Desktop/NumberPlate/` from the file names. So if the script cannot find the files on your machine, you might need to add those back to the code.